# Can't get GNU grep 2.12 to handle LF character in regex expression

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I've been at it for over an hour, but can't find why it's not working.

I'm searching an HTML document for "\nSome text". Simple enough.

But he following commands won't work:

```
grep -Po '(?s)<h2>\nSome text' input.html > output.html
grep -Po '(?s)<h2>\\nSome text' input.html > output.html
```

I need the "-P" switch since grep's basic regex engine doesn't support multiline.

I don't know what else to try. Any idea?

Thank you.

--
Edit: The input file simply contains this:

```
<h2>LF (ie. \n)
Some text
```

Comment: You need `-z` switch too..`-P` is for PCRE, not to support multiline..also note that your regex pattern does not seem correct to me..you have used dotall modifier but have not used it anywhere..it would be great if you could edit your question and add the input and expected output..

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the example for the question, but will use the dotall modifier in the actual regex.

When using -Pzo, the output file now says "Binary file input.html matches" instead of containing the segment I was looking for. Weird.

Comment: Its very hard to tell whats going on..please edit your question to add chunk of input file and your expected output from that..

Comment: Are you sure about the "-z" switch?

"-z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline"

Comment: Yes..i am..`-z` will cause each line to end in `NUL` rather than the end of line so that you can match the `\r` or `\n` using `.` as you are using dotall modifier..

Comment: Try `grep -Poz '(?s)<h2>.{1,2}Some text' file.txt`

Comment: It says "Binary file input.html matches". I guess it's considered "binary" because it's in UTF-8.

Comment: Try `grep -aPoz '(?s)<h2>.{1,2}Some text' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things to match the line breaks (hence multiple lines) using `grep` :

- `-z` option of newer GNU `grep`, it will cause the lines to be separated by ASCII NUL rather than line breaks
- `(?s)` is called DOTALL modifier (with `grep -P`), it will cause the `grep` to match the line breaks (LF/CR) by `.` (dot)

So in your case the following should work:

```
grep -aPoz '(?s)<h2>.Some text' file.txt
```

Here `.` will match the new line.

If you have CR and LF (or not sure) then:

```
grep -aPoz '(?s)<h2>.{1,2}Some text' file.txt
```

As `grep` was reading first few bytes to determine the file type hence your file was being treated as a binary file by `grep`, `-a` will cause the file to be treated as a text file.

Comment: `grep -Pzo '<h2>\nSome text'` would also work. See also `grep -Pzo '<h2>\RSome text'` to match any newline sequence (see "Newline sequences" section in pcrepattern man page)

Answer (score 0):

grep searches lines by default and can therefore normally not be used to find the character between lines.

When I search for newline characters I usually replace the newline character (assuming UNIX line breaks here) with a different character that I know not to exist in the text, like so:

```
cat file.html | sed 's/\n/%\n/g' | grep '<h2>%' | tr --delete %
```

However, it seems to me like you are searching  at the end of a line, which can be searched like this:

```
grep '<h2>$' file.html > newfile.html
```

since `$` is a regex(7) matching the end of a line (`^` matches the beginning).

Edit: If I got it wrong (I suspect so) and you need `<h2>\nSome text` then try something like this:

```
cat file.html | sed 's/<h2>\n/ñ/g' | grep 'ñSome text' | sed 's/ñ/<h2>\n/g' > newfile.html
```

using a different character (sequence in UTF-8) than `ñ` if you have actual `ñ`s in your text.

Or try a combination:

```
cat file.html | tr \\n % | sed 's/<h2>%/ñ/g' | tr % \\n | grep 'ñSome text' | sed 's/ñ/<h2>\n/g'
```

using a single character (in UTF-8) for `%` that is not used in the file.